# What is the solution to this inequality?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

This is the given inequality I've been trying to solve

$$1/6\leq \frac{1}{\mid x \mid} \leq 1/2$$

However the answer I get is $(0,6] \cup [2,6]$ which is not the answer given in my book. Could you please explain what I did wrong? I split it up into two inequalities $1/6\leq \frac{1}{\mid x \mid}$ and $\frac{1}{\mid x \mid} \leq 1/2$ and solved each individually. I've been trying to find a mistake in my calculations but I don't see one.

Comment: It is hard to see how you got $(0, 6]$ as part of your answer (by the way, $(0, 6] \cup [2, 6] = (0, 6]$) so it is hard to say what you did wrong.

Comment: I made the mistake of solving it as $1/6\leq \frac{1}{ x} \leq 1/2$ instead of $1/6\leq \frac{1}{\mid x \mid} \leq 1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: it is very helpful to flip the fractions (remembering to flip the inequalities): $$\frac{1}{6} \le \frac{1}{|x|} \le \frac{1}{2}\text{  implies  } 6 \ge |x| \ge 2.$$

Comment: You can do this meticulously: If $1/6 \le 1/|x|$ then, cross-multiplying, $|x| \le 6$ (so $x$ is in $[-6, 6]$). If $1/|x| \le 1/2$ then $|x| \ge 2$ (so $x$ is in $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$). Now take the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach is to base one's reasoning on a figure like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{6}\leq\frac{1}{|x|}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow 6\geq|x|\geq 2.$$ Now, $$|x|\leq 6\Leftrightarrow x\in[-6,6]$$ and $$|x|\geq 2\Leftrightarrow x\geq 2$$ or $$x\leq -2.$$ So $x\in[-6,-2]\cup[2,6].$

Answer (score 0):

You can first solve the question for $\frac 16\le \frac 1x\le \frac 12$ and after take the corresponding symmetric in the negative $x$-axis.

Since the function $f(x)=\frac 1x;\space x\gt 0$ is strictly decreasing you have just to solve $\frac 16=\frac 1x$ and $\frac 12=\frac 1x$

Hence $x\in [-6,-2]\cup [2,6]$